# Windows 2008R2 Scheduled Task Trigger - Not Equals Syntax?

Tags: windows, task, schedule

Does anyone know the syntax for Not Equals in the trigger for a Scheduled Task in Windows 2008R2?

I've got this syntax examples...

```
*[System[(Level=2 or Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=7036)]]and * [EventData [Data ([@ Name = 'param2'] and (Data = 'stopped'))
```

I want the last part 'Data = stopped' to be a not equals.  != and <> don't seem to work.

Update: Now with examples...

Comment: What do you want to do? - What should not eqal what?

Comment: And what exactly do you do with your example? Is it a line in a batch file? Do you read it to your server? What kind of microphone are you using? Are the drivers installed correctly? Is it plugged in? - Sorry to be a little belligerent, but you could supply all relevant information at once... ;)

Comment: I'm not looking for a review of code...just wanting to know if it's possible to do a not equals.

Comment: I do my task scheduling via Taskschd.msc. It has a GUI, so no, there is no way. The question does not even make sense. If you do not supply all the information to understand what you are trying to do, how do you suppose anyone could help you?

Comment: By providing simple knowledge or links to documentation that state whether or not the syntax is possible.  Which you just did, after some work to get it out of you. Thanks.